# Nonetype error on join() in filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename) in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, image-processing

I am creating a background subtractor app using Flask and I have created a function such that when i press upload button to display image on the screen and save to upload folder and press next button to move to the background subtraction result page

I am making an app with Flask and this is my app.py code

this is my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from background_subtractor import BackgroundSubtractor
import cv2
import webbrowser
import numpy as np
import base64
import os
```

```
app = Flask(__name__)

# Set up the upload folder
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), UPLOAD_FOLDER)

# Set up the static folder
STATIC_FOLDER = 'static'
app.config['STATIC_FOLDER'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), STATIC_FOLDER)



@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 

def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            #print("1",filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            #print("2",filename)
            return redirect(url_for('background_subtractor', filename=filename))
    return render_template('upload.html', next_button=True)



@app.route('/background_subtractor')
def background_subtractor():
    # Get the filename of the uploaded image from the query parameters
    filename = request.args.get('filename')
    #print("343",filename)
    # Get the paths of the uploaded file and the masked image file
    filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
    #print("4",filename)
    masked_filename = 'masked_' + filename
    masked_filepath = os.path.join(app.config['STATIC_FOLDER'], masked_filename)

    # Load the image from file
    image = cv2.imread(filepath)

    # Create a BackgroundSubtractor object and process the image
    bg_subtractor = BackgroundSubtractor(filepath, masked_filepath)
    mask = bg_subtractor.apply(image)

    # Save the masked image to file
    cv2.imwrite(masked_filepath, mask)

    # Render the background subtractor template and pass the filenames
    return render_template('background_subtractor.html', filename=filename, masked_filename=masked_filename)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    webbrowser.open('http://localhost:5000/')
    app.run(debug=False)
```

upload.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Image</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload Image</h1>
    <form id="upload-form" action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif" required>
        <button type="submit" name="upload">Upload</button>
    </form>
    <div id="preview-container"></div>
    {% if filename %}
        <p>Uploaded file:</p>
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=filename) }}" width="500">
    {% endif %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('background_subtractor', filename=filename) }}" method="GET">
        <button type="submit" name="next">Next</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        const uploadForm = document.getElementById('upload-form');
        uploadForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
            const file = fileInput.files[0];
            const previewContainer = document.getElementById("preview-container");
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function() {
                const image = new Image();
                image.src = reader.result;
                image.width = 500;
                previewContainer.innerHTML = '';
                previewContainer.appendChild(image);
            }

            // Read the image file as a data URL
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            // Submit the form to upload the image and redirect to the next page
            const formData = new FormData(uploadForm);
            fetch(uploadForm.action, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            }).then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.text();
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Error uploading file');
                }
            }).then(data => {
                console.log('File uploaded:', data);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

background subtractor.html

> 

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
>     <title>Background Subtraction</title>
>     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
> </head>
> <body>
>     <h1>Background Subtraction</h1>
>     <div>
>         <p>Original image:</p>
>         <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=filename) }}" width="500">
>     </div>
>     <div>
>         <p>Masked image:</p>
>         <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=masked_filename) }}" width="500">
>     </div>
> </body>
> </html>
```

even though the masked and original file are getting saved to my upload and static folder but when i run the app i get this error when i press the Next button to navigate from the upload page to the background subtractor page. i debugged it, when i print the filename in the background_subtractor function, it prints twice, first current and then none